# How to create a text popup in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, console, popups

In Windows conhost there's a setting for **popup colors** like this

[image]

Some of the available popups can be accessed from cmd if you press <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>F9</kbd>). The same can be done in PowerShell by temporarily unloading the PSReadLine module with `Remove-Module -Name PSReadLine`

I guest that feature uses some [console API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) but I couldn't find any relevant functions.
**How can I create a similar popup from a PowerShell script?**

[image: popup in powershell]

Comment: You've already said. -'The same can be done in PowerShell by temporarily unloading the PSReadLine module with Remove-Module -Name PSReadLine'. So, what are you after? What you are seeing is from the OS of course and coded into the DLL in the OS. You can't impact UI at the OS level, without C/C++ code. In PS, you can write borderless forms, which means code has to be loaded at every instance.

Comment: @postanote I want to create a popup of my own text. And you're wrong, PowerShell can interact with all .NET and all native functions. I just couldn't find a proper win32 API to do that

Comment: I fully understand that PS has access to all things .Net, but you seem to be saying you are trying to replicate this core OS popup in PS, via hotkeys. If you are saying, you want this hotkey stuff while in a PS session, then .Net namespace as you need to, yet, with the need to disable PSReadline each time to to use your goodies, is well, you know. Yet, all have their reasons, choices and options to make.

Comment: @postanote I simply want to create a popup that's drawn over the current console then close it as I described in the title. Simple as that. I don't care about whatever way to invoke it. I never said that I want to show a popup with the history commands when I press a shortcut key. You're thinking too much